# Finding autocovariance of AR(2)

Tags: time-series

Could someone explain why I didn't get the same answer?

This is an AR(2),
$$X_t={\phi_0}+{\phi_1}{X_{t-1}}+{\phi_2}{X_{t-2}}+{Z_t} \hspace{6 mm} \text{where } Z_t \sim WN(0, \sigma^2)$$

$\begin{align*}
\gamma(0) &= \rm{cov}(X_t, X_t)\\
          &= \rm{cov}({\phi_0}+{\phi_1}{X_{t-1}}+{\phi_2}{X_{t-2}}+{Z_t},\hspace{3 mm} {\phi_0}+{\phi_1}{X_{t-1}}+{\phi_2}{X_{t-2}}+{Z_t})  \hspace{6 mm} \text{(by definition)}\\
          &= \rm{cov}({\phi_1}{X_{t-1}}+{\phi_2}{X_{t-2}}+{Z_t}, \hspace{3 mm} {\phi_1}{X_{t-1}}+{\phi_2}{X_{t-2}}+{Z_t})\\
          &= \rm{cov}({\phi_1}{X_{t-1}}, {\phi_1}{X_{t-1}})+ \rm{cov}({\phi_1}{X_{t-1}},  {\phi_2}{X_{t-2}}) + \rm{cov}({\phi_2}{X_{t-2}},  {\phi_1}{X_{t-1}}) +  \rm{cov}({\phi_2}{X_{t-2}}, {\phi_2}{X_{t-2}}) + \sigma^2\\
          &= {\phi_1^2\gamma(0)} + {\phi_1}{\phi_2}\gamma(1) + {\phi_1}{\phi_2}\gamma(1) + \phi_2^2\gamma(0) + \sigma^2\\
          &=  (\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2)\gamma(0) + 2{\phi_1}{\phi_2}\gamma(1) + \sigma^2\\
\text{So, we get}\\  
\gamma(0) &= (\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2)\gamma(0) + 2{\phi_1}{\phi_2}\gamma(1) + \sigma^2\\
(1-\phi_1-\phi_2)\gamma(0) &= 2{\phi_1}{\phi_2}\gamma(1) + \sigma^2\\
\gamma(0)  &= \frac{2{\phi_1}{\phi_2}\gamma(1) + \sigma^2}{(1-\phi_1-\phi_2)}\\
\end{align*}$

This is the final answer, but it is not correct.  It is derived as the following,
$\begin{align*}
X_t &={\phi_0}+{\phi_1}{X_{t-1}}+{\phi_2}{X_{t-2}}+{Z_t}\\
X_tX_t &={\phi_0}+{\phi_1}{X_tX_{t-1}}+{\phi_2}{X_tX_{t-2}}+{X_tZ_t}\\
E[X_t^2] &={\phi_0}+{\phi_1}E[{X_tX_{t-1}}]+{\phi_2}E[{X_tX_{t-2}}]+E[{X_tZ_t}] \hspace{3 mm}\\
\text{(note: }\rm{cov}(x,y)=E[xy]- E[x]E[y])\\ 
\text{(Where did the 2nd term } E[x]E[y] \text{ go}???)\\
\gamma(0)&= {\phi_0}+{\phi_1}\gamma(1)+{\phi_2}\gamma(2)+\sigma^2 \\
\end{align*}$

Why are two answers different?  Is one of them wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first computation is correct, just be carefull just after the "so we get":
$$
\gamma(0) = \frac{2\phi_1\phi_2\gamma(1) - \sigma^2}{1-\phi_1^2-\phi_2^2}
$$

The second one is ok:
$$EX_t^2 = \phi_0 EX_t+ \phi_1 EX_t X_{t-1}+ \phi_2 EX_t X_{t-2} + E[X_t Z_t] $$
Now substract
$$
[EX_t]^2 = \phi_0 [EX_t]+ \phi_1  EX_t EX_{t-1}+ \phi_2 EX_t EX_{t-2} + EX_t E Z_t
$$
and using $\rm{cov}(X_t,Z_t) = \sigma^2$ you get:

$$
\gamma(0) = \phi_1  \gamma(1)+ \phi_2 \gamma(2) + \sigma^2
$$

This is a particular case of the [Yule-Walker equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Yule-Walker_equations).

Comment: They don't look like they will give the same answer for $\gamma(0)$.

Comment: Do not forget that there is a different variable in the second equation: $\gamma(2)$.

Comment: btw, at line "Where did the 2nd term E[x]E[y] go???" that term is NOT zero, why did it go away?

Comment: Did you read my answer?